# How can I create a List of random int numbers without repeating?

Tags: c#, .net

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;
int[] test2 = new int[5]; 

Random randNum = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < test2.Length; i++)
{
    test2[i] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

How can I make sure that the numbers between 0 and 20 will not be the same in the array ? For example I don't want to have in the array twice the number 5.

And how to do it with a List ? or array is better ?

Comment: Did you tried?  Does it repeats?

Comment: Fill a `List<int>` with `Min` to `Max`. Then [Randomize the List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt). Then `Take()` some items.

Comment: Why not [try this??](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+How+can+I+create+a+List+of+random+int+numbers+without+repeating&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use LINQ. (By generating a sequence between Min and Max with `Enumerable.Range`):

```
var rnd = new Random();
var res = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max - Min + 1).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

And if you want to pick specific number of the sequence you can use `Take` method. Like this:

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max - Min + 1).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: This method is probably best, it doesn't require 256MB of memory (like stroing an array of all possible integers), and it is guaranteed to terminate unlike any meothd which involves ignoring generated duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of Max length and insert numbers from 0 to Max. Then use a random algorithm to choose one element of the array (possibly mod(Max-chosenElementsNumber)). After delete element from array. Done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `HashSet<int>`, it doesn't allow duplicates.

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;
var test2 = new HashSet<int>();

Random randNum = new Random();
while(test2.Count < 5)
{
    test2.Add(randNum.Next(Min, Max));
}
```

You can also randomize with **LINQ**:

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;

Random randNum = new Random();

var test2 = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max - Min + 1)
                      .OrderBy(x => randNum.Next())
                      .Take(5)
                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just continue to get another random number if you get a duplicated one.

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;
int[] test2 = new int[5];

Random randNum = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < test2.Length; i++)
{
    int r;
    do
    {
        r = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
    } while (test2.Contains(r));
    test2[i] = r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal method of sorting integers 0 to 19

```
            List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> numbers = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

            Random randNum = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,int>(i, randNum.Next()) );
            }
            numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray()));
            Console.ReadLine();
```